# Send additional data with form_data on ajax

Tags: php, ajax

First, let me give a demo demonstrating what behavior I would like to achieve.

```
    $('#multiple_files').change(function(){

      var form_data = new FormData();
       for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++)
       {
         form_data.append("file[]", document.getElementById('multiple_files').files[i]);
       }
     if(error_images == '')
     {
       var user_id = 1;
       var office_id = 2;
        $.ajax({
         url:"upload.php",
         method:"POST",
         data: {form_data:form_data, user_id:user_id, office_id:office_id},
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData: false,
         beforeSend:function(){
            $('#error_multiple_files').html('<br /><label class="text-primary">Uploading...</label>');
         },   
         success:function(data)
         {
          $('#error_multiple_files').html('<br /><label class="text-success">Uploaded</label>');
               load_image_data();
          console.log(data);
         }
   });
  }


    }
```

The problem in here, if i send form_data on ajax like 'data:form_data' everything works perfect. But i need to send also user_id and office_id with form_data like above code.

Comment: I think you should add those extra fields to the FormData object itself

Answer (score 0):

```
form_data.append('user_id', user_id);
form_data.append('office_id', office_id);
```

Comment: Please add some comment to your answer, not just a code.

Comment: How can i use those variables inside php ?

Comment: @TugceAksoz they should be available in the $_POST array just like a normal form submission